# If statement with ZERO as condition

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I am readin linux sources and notice statements like

```
if (0) {
....
}
```

What is this magic about?
Example: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/include/asm/percpu.h#L132

Comment: `0` is considered to be `false`, while anything non-zero is `true`. This line is equivalent to `if(false)`, and anything inside the brackets will not be run. Usually this is done when a developer wants to turn some functionality on/off at compile time (e.g., debugging code).

Comment: @wolfPack88: It's equivalent to `if(false)` only if `false` is defined. It's defined as a keyword in C++. In C, it exists only if you're using C99 or later *and* have `#include <stdbool.h>`, or if you've defined it yourself. (I think the kernel does the latter.)

Comment: @KeithThompson: The question was tagged C++ when I commented, the tag was changed to C later. Not sure why that was...

Comment: @wolfPack88: Probably because it's also tagged linux-kernel. (The linux kernel is written in C, not C++.)

Answer (score 8):

In this particular *macro* you're referring to:

```
132         if (0) {                                                        \
133                 pao_T__ pao_tmp__;                                      \
134                 pao_tmp__ = (val);                                      \
135                 (void)pao_tmp__;                                        \
136         }                                                               \
```

the `if (0) { ... }` block is a way of "using" `val` without actually *using* it.  The body of this block of code will be evaluated by the compiler, but no code will actually be generated, as an `if (0)` should always be eliminated - it can never run.

Note that this is a macro. As such, `var` and `val` may be of any type - the preprocessor doesn't care. `pao_T__` is `typedef`ed to `typeof(var)`. As [Andy Shevchenko pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020617/if-statement-with-zero-as-condition/29020707?noredirect=1#comment46286467_29020707), this block of code exists to ensure that `val` and `var` are type-compatible, by creating a variable of the same type as `var`, and assigning `val` to it. If the types weren't compatible, this assignment would generate a compiler error.

In general, many of the Linux kernel header files should be considered black magic. They are an interesting example of the *meta programming* that one can do with the C preprocessor, usually for the sake of performance.

Comment: *"but no code will actually be generated"* -- May not be accurate if optimization is disabled.

Comment: Your suspicion is wrong :-) It's simple type checking that `var` and `val` have the same one.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko Perfect, thank you. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I recently started reading the Linux source as well. It is definitely an education in the wild and wonderful things the C preprocessor can do! While this doesn't involve the preprocessor, I found it interesting that they deliberately call non-existent functions in some places -- so that if the C optimizer doesn't optimize a block of code out, the linker will throw an error. In spirit, it's very similar to the code in this question.

Comment: @AlexD Note that they *do* call a nonexistant function in this macro: `__bad_percpu_size();` :-)